# can I send Whatsapp programmatically in my app flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, whatsapp

I want to send WhatsApp messages in bulk, meaning my goal is that if the user gives me consent. I will be able to connect to his WhatsApp and send WhatsApp messages to a list of numbers that I will provide. Note: I don't want the user to leave my app, meaning I don't want the regular functionality that the WhatsApp app is opened with the number. I want that after the user's consent, I will be able to use the user WhatsApp to send around 200 WhatsApp messages automatically without leaving my app.
I saw the related answers each one did not work for me.
[first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266063/can-i-use-whatsapp-in-my-app-for-sending-message) - the regular functionality that just opened WhatsApp.

[whatsapp flutter lib](https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp) from what I saw, I can not send messages to a user who does not have WhatsApp for business.
[android send whatsapp](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-send-message-on-whatsapp-in-android/) I saw this message that will allow me to do this in android only, and I need to find a way to write a custom function in Kotlin or Java to make it work.
[flutter whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892495/how-to-send-a-message-directly-from-my-flutter-app-to-whatsapp-using-urllauncher) - I saw the answers, but none of them told me if I could send a bulk of messages without opening the actual app.

I should note: there me be another approach that can work. Create a shortcut programmatically for ios, which will allow me to create a shortcut that will include the list of numbers with the text and activate the shortcut. But I could not figure out also how to do so.
On the apple form, someone asks this question and does not answer.
[swift create a shortcut](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/110470)

tech: flutter, firebase

Answer (score -1):

You will need to see what APIs WhatsApp has available that you can utilize. There isn't a current way to just send bulk messages directly from your app and they get sent in whatsapp. You need to work with WhatsApp's APIs to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: But as I mentioned, there is a way in ios that is to create a shortcut to send a message.

Comment: You asked for a way to do both and I'm giving you a direct answer to how to do that. You should get acquainted with their apis and setup your own backend cloud functions to handle this for both. It'll be significantly easier than trying to do custom solutions on both sides.

Comment: The problem is that it has to be sent from my WhatsApp number, and my users what the messages to be sent from their number.

Comment: yes, but their apis will do so much more than that. All these packages you see out there that handle this stuff, all use their apis. So you might as well just use them yourself so that you can accomplish the specific things you're trying to do.